# Is this bluetooth headphone audio-interruption issue rooted with windows, bluetooth, or are my particular headphones retarded?

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

So I picked up my first set of bluetooth headphones (I'd been using USB wireless before hand). They have a nasty issue when being used with windows though.

When they connect, they create two different audio devices. They create a Headphones playback devices which is auto set to the default device and they create a Headset playback device which is the Default Communication device.

When I am listening to music throughout the day the Headphones profile is in use and everything sounds clear and pleasant. When I go into a skype meeting it apparently switches over to the Headset profile which splits the communication channel bandwidth between the microphone and the speakers (per the headphone support).

This is irritating but tolerable -- I probably shouldn't be listening to music during skype calls or some such, even if the conversation is more boring than watching paint dry.

The intolerable part is that if windows makes a noise during skype calls (an error dialog, an email alert, a skype message recieved noise) the headphones temporarily switch back over to the headphones profile -- My microphone cuts off and I lose the meeting audio.

Can someone tell me if this is a known issue with windows or bluetooth, or do I just have crappy headphones? For reference, I got them off of amazon for $45, so "You have crappy headphones" is an entirely understandable answer.

Comment: It happens with all BT headphones and no, you shouldn't be listening to music while in Skype, at least not with the same device.

Comment: @MichaelBay Ouch -- Not what I wanted to hear (back to wired it is), but that's a perfectly acceptable answer. If you post it I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bluetooth headphones with microphone support two distinct Bluetooth profiles:

- [A2DP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_(A2DP)) (HiFi Stereo Audio, no microphone input)
- [HFP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Hands-Free_Profile_(HFP)) (AKA "ḧands-free" = Mono Audio + microphone)

(Optional: [AVRCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Audio/Video_Remote_Control_Profile_(AVRCP)))

This Bluetooth profiles have distinct applications. A2DP is commonly used for audio streaming and HFP for two-way ("duplex") voice communications.

Windows by default sets it to A2DP.

Whilst there's nothing preventing its use for audio streaming in HFP mode, other then the audio quality, applications requiring the use of the microphone must force the OS to change the profile to HFP if A2DP is currently set. Skype, like any other VoIP application, does exactly that - otherwise the microphone wouldn't work - and when the switch happens some errors messages, warnings or alerts are to be expected and are normal.

In order to avoid this behavior, switch it to HFP prior to initializing a Skype call. Music and a Skype call at the same time is therefore not recommended. This advice isn't applicable to other types of headphones, analogue or USB. The former is just a passive device dependent on the sound card/chip which typically can manage multiple sound sources at once; the latter is a digital device (using generic USB audio drivers) 
that also can manage multiple sources. Think of it as an additional, external, sound card with roughly the same capabilities as any other sound card. That is not the case with Bluetooth audio due to protocol constraints.